# FreeMarker Java 8 Optional value support

Tags: java-8, freemarker, option-type

Does FreeMarker support Optional value in Java 8?

e.g. I have String id, and its getter method is like:

```
public Optional<String> getId() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(Id);
}
```

How am I going to reference it in the .ftl file. It seems that {data.id} can not find the correct Optional value. But gives me Optional[1334586]

Answer (score 9):

Well, Freemarker is not supposed to be aware of Optional or it is better to say that its dynamically typed so it works for any object.

Since you calling ${data.id} it's just calls `toString` on `Optional` which is totally expected behavior.

If you want to handle null values in your template and for that you want to use `Optional`, you may choose to set a default value if null, so `Optional` usage won't be needed:

```
    Synopsis: unsafe_expr!default_expr or unsafe_expr! or (unsafe_expr)!default_expr or (unsafe_expr)!
    Example: ${data.id!"No id."}
```

Or check if it's exists:

```
<#if data?? && data.id??>
  Id found
<#else>
  Id not found
</#if>
```

For more info check out the Freemarker [docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html). Specifically parts: Handling missing values and Missing value test operator.

If you just want to get the value from `Optional` in your template:

```
${data.id.orElse('')}
```

or

```
${data.id.get()!''}
```